# Raspberry Pi loses connection when external drive is plugged in

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb3

## The situation

I have a USB-C Samsung external drive. I bought a USB-A adapter adapter for it so that I can plug it into my new Raspberry Pi 4. It is running Raspbian OS with the latest updates. My Pi is connected via wired connection.

## What happens

As soon as I plug the external drive into the Pi, my Pi loses its network connection.

- I can't SSH to it
- My Router doesn't have it in its DHCP table

## What I've Tried

- I have tried plugging in the drive multiple times.
- I have tried rebooting the Pi.
- I have tried plugging the drive into a different port.

Comment: Does your Pi4 have enough juice to run?

Comment: Are you sure that it just loses the network connection, or does it shutdown?

Comment: And what about the logs?

Comment: Does the drive work in another computer?

Comment: @MatsKarlsson Where can I find the logs and which ones should I look at?

Comment: @Andyroo Yes it does

Comment: @Reishin You and goldilocks solved it! Thank you! It did not have enough juice! I switched the Pi to its own adapter and everything works!

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you! You and Reishin solved it! I would have never thought of that on my own!

Comment: Please create an answer for the solution and mark it as the accepted one after two days with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of problem as solved by @Reishin and @goldilocks was that the Pi didn't have enough power for itself and the drive.
The solution to the problem is to connect the Pi to its own adapter. It was previously plugged into my router.